Modeling generic recursive data structures using classes and subclasses and recursive generic constraints
I'm trying to model a binary search tree (BST) and a Statistic BST that extends the BST with an additional size property. I've been experimenting with three different approaches:

Recursive
Polymorphic
Bounded polymorphic

// 1. Recursive.
interface IBSTRec<K, V> {
    key: K;
    value: V;
    left?: IBSTRec<K, V>;
    right?: IBSTRec<K, V>;
}

class BSTRec<K, V> implements IBSTRec<K, V> {
    constructor(
        public key: K, 
        public value: V, 
        public left?: BSTRec<K, V>, 
        public right?: BSTRec<K, V>
    ) { /* ... */ }

    insert(node: BSTRec<K, V>): BSTRec<K, V> {
        // Insert logic...
        return node;
    }
}

interface IStatisticBSTRec<K, V> extends BSTRec<K, V> {
    size: number;
}

class StatisticBSTRec<K, V> extends BSTRec<K, V> {
    size = 1;

    constructor(key: K, value: V, left?: StatisticBSTRec<K, V>, right?: StatisticBSTRec<K, V>) {
        super(key, value, left, right);
        this.size += (left?.size || 0) + (right?.size || 0);
    }

    insert(node: StatisticBSTRec<K, V>): StatisticBSTRec<K, V> {
        const inserted = super.insert(node);
        // Update size for inserted node's ancestors...
        return inserted as StatisticBSTRec<K, V>;
    }
}

The recursive approach doesn't seem to fit subclasses well; each base method needs to be overridden in a subclass in order to change its signature to match the subclass type.
// 2. Polymorphic.
interface IBSTPoly<K, V> {
    key: K;
    value: V;
    left?: this;
    right?: this;
}

class BSTPoly<K, V> implements IBSTPoly<K, V> {
    key: K;
    value: V;
    left?: this;
    right?: this;
    constructor(key: K, value: V, left?: BSTPoly<K, V>, right?: BSTPoly<K, V>) {
         this.key = key;
         this.value = value;
         if (left) this.left = left as this;
         if (right) this.right = right as this;
    }

    insert(node: this): this {
        // Insert logic...
        return this;
    }
}

interface IStatisticBSTPoly<K, V> extends IBSTPoly<K, V> {
    size: number;
}

class StatisticBSTPoly<K, V> extends BSTPoly<K, V> implements IStatisticBSTPoly<K, V> {
    size = 1;

    constructor(key: K, value: V, left?: StatisticBSTPoly<K, V>, right?: StatisticBSTPoly<K, V>) {
        super(key, value, left, right);
        this.size += (left?.size || 0) + (right?.size || 0);
    }

    insert(node: this): this {
        const inserted = super.insert(node);
        // Update size for inserted node's ancestors...
        // Unlike 1. Recursive, we don't have to type assert here anymore.
        return inserted;
    }
}

I'm pretty happy with the polymorphic approach but I decided to continue my exploration using TypeScript's generic variable constraints to describe the recursive relationship between nodes. This, however, is where I ran into a problem:
// 3. Bounded Polymorphic.
interface IBSTBoRec<K, V, T extends IBSTBoRec<K, V, T> = IBSTBoRec<K, V, any>> {
    key: K;
    value: V;
    left?: T;
    right?: T;
}

// Can't use T for its own default, so using any.
class BSTBoRec<K, V, T extends BSTBoRec<K, V, T> = BSTBoRec<K, V, any>> implements IBSTBoRec<K, V, T> {
    constructor(
        public key: K, 
        public value: V, 
        public left?: T, 
        public right?: T
    ) { /* ... */ }

    insert(node: T): T {
        // Insert logic...
        return node;
    }
}

interface IStatisticBSTBoRec<K, V, T extends IStatisticBSTBoRec<K, V, T> = IStatisticBSTBoRec<K, V, any>> 
        extends IBSTBoRec<K, V, T> {
    size: number;
}

class StatisticBSTBoRec<K, V, T extends StatisticBSTBoRec<K, V, T> = StatisticBSTBoRec<K, V, any>> 
        extends BSTBoRec<K, V, T> implements IStatisticBSTBoRec<K, V, T> {
    size = 1;

    constructor(key: K, value: V, left?: T, right?: T) {
        super(key, value, left, right);
        this.size += (left?.size || 0) + (right?.size || 0);
    }

    insert(node: T): T {
        const inserted = super.insert(node);
        // Update size for inserted node's ancestors...
        return inserted;
    }
}

What's the correct way to define defaults for T in the bounded polymorphic approach, without using any? (T can't be used to define its own default. I.e. IBSTBoRec<K, V, T extends IBSTBoRec<K, V, T> = IBSTBoRec<K, V, T>> is not allowed.)
Here's a playground with the code.

Please [edit] this to ask a single primary question, or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

@jcalz Updated. Only one question now, but I left in the recursive and polymorphic lead-up to make it clear that I considered using both before going on to recursive constraints. Nevertheless, let me know if you think the lead-up is superfluous as well, and I can remove it.

Maybe you're looking to make a recursive type as the default as shown in this playground link? If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Ah, that's brilliant, but there seems to be a problem with leaving the left branch as undefined, while providing a right. Here's a playground to show what I mean.

Hm, it seems like the inference needs some help to get it right in that case. Here's a playground where explicitly saying what K and V is fixes it, though I don't understand why yet.

That's an inference issue and doesn't seem to be in scope for the question. You could always manually specify the types like this. Feels like a followup question for another post. How do you want to proceed?

I think the default approach you've suggested works for me. I'm happy to accept an answer based on that. In the meanwhile, I'll work on another question regarding the inference problem when the (right) branch type is incorrectly inferred from the absence of left.

It definitely seems like the recursive default confuses the heck out of the inference algorithm. Given the particular example here I might just brute force it with overloads as shown in this playground link. Otherwise I really don't know what to say, since NoInfer isn't granular enough to stop the weird behavior here... it sure looks like T begins to be inferred as undefined (which doesn't meet the constraint) and then that partial candidate gets used later. Blecch.

This is interesting. I created another question with a smaller example that reproduces this problem.

It's true that default type arguments cannot reference themselves. However, types in general can reference themselves, so you can make a new type alias for the intended default, and then use it.
So you can convert
interface IBSTBoRec<K, V, 
    T extends IBSTBoRec<K, V, T> = IBSTBoRec<K, V, ???>> {
    key: K;
    value: V;
    left?: T;
    right?: T;
}

into
type IBSTBoRecDflt<K, V> = IBSTBoRec<K, V, IBSTBoRecDflt<K, V>>;

interface IBSTBoRec<K, V,
    T extends IBSTBoRec<K, V, T> = IBSTBoRecDflt<K, V>> {
    key: K;
    value: V;
    left?: T;
    right?: T;
}

This compiles fine now. It may or may not ultimately meet your specific needs, but it's a way out of the self-referential default issue.  You can apply that to the other defaults in your example code as well.
Playground link to code
